# What is really taught in CS undergraduate OS courses?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science

I took an undergraduate OS course, but it was really teaching the OS concepts, like memory & process management, file systems, and disk, etc...
But doesn’t really go that deep, like how the OS(windows/Linux) kernel is developed and the details of how they work.
I’m guessing it’s because the details are too difficult for undergraduates. Is that it?

Comment: It would truly depend on the course. Some courses have case studies where how the OS works are shown.

Answer (score 1):

The topics covered in the course you took are indeed those generally seen in a first course in Operating Systems, typically aimed at undergraduates. Truly understanding these topics can be difficult, so the implementation details of an OS (and actually implementing an OS) is generally a separate course whose prerequisite is the first course.

One of the course breakdowns I've seen is:

1. undergraduate OS (covering the topics you took)
2. OS Implementation (either undergrad or grad-level)
3. graduate OS (research focussed)

If your university doesn't offer an OS Implementation course, checkout [MIT's OS Implementation course](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.S081/2020/index.html).